# What is statistical fault localization?

Tags: real-analysis, statistics

I heard a talk, and was wondering what it is.   There seem to be articles that point to the methods of this, but what is it?

Either ELI5 or in depth answers are appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

Statistical fault localization is an application of statistics.  Given multiple successful and unsuccessful runs of a system or process, the goal is to determine what parts of the system were responsible for the unsuccessful runs.  This is done by instrumenting the system to collect detailed information about what each part did during the run, and then learning a statistical relationship between this information and the success of the run.

As a simple example, suppose we want to find bugs in a computer program.  We instrument the program to record which statements were executed during a run.  Then we run the program with many different inputs and record whether it crashed or gave an invalid output.  This gives a data table where each row is a run, there is one column per statement indicated whether it ran or not, and there is one column indicating whether the run succeeded.  A variety of statistical models can be applied to such data.  Suppose we use logistic regression.  Then each statement will get a weight reflecting its importance toward success or failure.  The statements with negative weights are the ones that often lead to failure so are likely to contain bugs.  Of course, this is only the simplest type of analysis one might do, and much more complex methods are possible.